# Disable CSS animation on window resize

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a CSS animation that makes the logo big on window load and then shrinks it down to size. Works great, however if I shrink down the window and then make it big again, the animation replays. Is there someway I can incorporate jQuery (or a CSS fix) that will disable the animation after it loads once? I thought I could do something with `animation-play-state: paused;` but I want it to play once so I'm not sure how I'd go about that.

Maybe onLoad assign class and then unassign class after animation is completed. Just thinking that might work? Anyone have any thoughts on how I'd go about that?

```
#logo {
    max-width: 260px;
    height: auto;
    width: 40%;
    -webkit-animation: animate 3s ease;
-moz-animation: animate 3s ease;
-ms-animation: animate 3s ease;
-o-animation: animate 3s ease;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery for this by testing the changed CSS property and behave accordingly:

for instance:
JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // run test on initial page load
    checkSize();

    // run test on resize of the window
    $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

//Function to the css rule
function checkSize(){
    if ($(".logo").css("float") == "none" ){
        // your code here
    }
}
```

your css:

```
    .logo {float:left;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .logo {float:none;}
}
```

[source](http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries)